# How to turn values of a list where words and numbers are stored as str into int for further processing

Tags: python, list, map-function

I have the following list:

Attributes are listed in first row and dummy variables check whether a certain candy type fits this critea. The last column shows the "success value" of a certain candy type in each row

[image: 1]

I read that using the map function would be "the most elegant, pythonic and recommended method to perform this particular task."

So attempted to apply the map function to my list (here stored as 'data') as follows:

```
data_int=list(map(int, data)) print(data_int)
```

However, I get the error code

"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Whoppers'"

for the first line.
("Whoppers" being the first element of the last line of the table)

Can anyone please explain me my error and what to do in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you exclude your headers while processing data?

Comment: I do not think so. However, as I am pretty much a beginner at Python (obivously :D) I do not know how.

Comment: try `next("variable_name",none)` where you are storing csv data  before performing map thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you are trying to do. Could you add an example of what `data` contains?

The error is generated because you are attempting to convert every element in `data` to an int. This includes the names of the candies, which is not possible to convert to a numerical value, causing the error message.

If you run `int("Whopper")` in the interpreter you will get this error message.

If `data` is in the form: `["Whopper", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1"]` then running `list(map(int,data[1:]))` will give you the result that I think you are looking for, since the operator `[1:]` excludes the first element of the list (in your case, the name of the candy).

Comment: The structure/content of 'data' is shown in the screenshot. I am attempting to convert the numerical entries of data into integer values. But since there are also names in it - as you have rightly pointed out - I am unable to accomplish this task.

Comment: Your question only shows an excel screenshot, it does not show the structure of `data` in python itself. I have edited my answer to give a little more information (showing how to exclude the first element of the list, which is causing the problems), let me know if this helps!

Comment: regarding your edit: I have changed my code according to your input. My current error code is "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.87199998'"  I read somewhere to include float here but I do not really know how as it also leads to an error

Comment: as additional help: running print(data) gives me "['Whoppers', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '.87199998', '.84799999', '49.524113']"

Comment: This error is generated since you are trying to covert a string representation of a non-integer to an integer, and this appears to generate an error. The way to fix this is to instead use `list(map(float,data[1:]))` (notice that 'int' has changed to 'float'). Floats in Python are able to represent non-integers, whereas ints only represent integers.

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: of course! sorry, am rather new to stackoverflow so I need to learn proper basic customs here as well

Answer (score 1):

The following are totally acceptable in python:

- passing a string representation of an integer into int
- passing a string representation of a float into float
- passing a string representation of an integer into float
- passing a float into int
- passing an integer into float

You are getting a ValueError cause you are passing a string representation of a float into int. If you still want to pass a string representation of a float to an int you can typecast to a float first, then to an integer like this

```
int(float('11.000000'))
```

Comment: so like this "data_int=list(map(int, float(data)))"?  That returns " float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'". Any idea how to cope with that?